# By deflation prove that the following equation has only one real root.

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

The equation is $$ f(x)=x^3+2x^2+10x-20=0.$$
Can anyone tell me what the method of deflation is and how I would use it to prove the statement?

I found the root $x=1.3688$ by using Newtons method.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section of [Factoring polynomials using the deflation method](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/poly_2.htm) explains deflation. In summary, it says you find an initial root $r$ of the polynomial, such as by trial & error, or inspecting the graph, then

> we find the other factor by dividing the polynomial by $(x − r)$. This is called **deflating the polynomial**.

It says to repeat this until no more real roots can be found.

In your case, you have found a root of $r \approx 1.3688$ by using Newton's method. As such, the procedure is to divide $x - 1.3688$ into your original polynomial, which gives (accurate to about $4$ decimal places for the constant term)

$$x^3 + 2x^2 + 10x − 20 \approx \left(x - 1.3688\right)\left(x^2 + 3.3688x + 14.6112\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Next, according to the method of deflation, you should graph the function $g\left(x\right) = x^2 + 3.3688x + 14.6112$ to confirm there are no more zeros, or according to an example in the referenced Web page, you can use the "grouping" method as provided in its [section 8.3](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/factoring_3.htm#type2).

Alternatively, you can note the discriminant of $b^2 - 4ac = 3.3688^2 - 4\left(14.6112\right) \approx -47.0959 \lt 0$, to show it has no real roots. In addition, you can just use the derivative of the original $3$rd degree polynomial, as used in the other $2$ current answers.

Comment: @MANONMARS45 You are welcome. I believe deflation was mostly used originally before we had computers, graphing calculators, etc., to determine the factors, so it's not taught too much any more. Also, in at least certain cases, like for just showing there's only $1$ real root in your cubic equation question, I believe using the derivative is faster & easier.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$f'(x)=3x^2+4x+10>0,$$ which says that $f$ increases.

Also, $f(1)<0$, $f(2)>0$ and $f$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this method known as the method of deflation?

Comment: @MANONMARS45 As I explain in my answer, "deflation" of a polynomial is basically repeating the steps of finding an exact or approximate root, and then dividing that root into the polynomial (thus reducing its degree by $1$ (i.e., "deflating" it)), until you can show there are no more real roots.

Answer (score 1):

$$  3 x^2 + 4 x + 10  $$ 
is always positive. 
$$ 3 \left(x + \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + \frac{26}{3} $$

I have no idea what the method of deflation might be